# ffmpeg selecting GPU: Intel Xe and Nvidia

Tags: ffmpeg

I have Nvidia RX A1000 and Intel Xe on my computer.

When trying to use qsv

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "Recording.mkv" -c:v av1_qsv -c:a copy out.mkv
```

I get the error

```
ffmpeg version 6.1.1-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --pkg-config=pkgconf --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-libvpl --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavcodec     60. 31.102 / 60. 31.102
  libavformat    60. 16.100 / 60. 16.100
  libavdevice    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavfilter     9. 12.100 /  9. 12.100
  libswscale      7.  5.100 /  7.  5.100
  libswresample   4. 12.100 /  4. 12.100
  libpostproc    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Recording.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 02:03:15.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11557 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 2560x1060 [SAR 1:1 DAR 128:53], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 02:03:15.000000000
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 02:03:14.990000000
File 'out.mkv' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> av1 (av1_qsv))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[av1_qsv @ 000002b15c6300c0] Current codec type is unsupported
[av1_qsv @ 000002b15c6300c0] some encoding parameters are not supported by the QSV runtime. Please double check the input parameters.
[vost#0:0/av1_qsv @ 000002b15bcae1c0] Error while opening encoder - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height.
Error while filtering: Function not implemented
[out#0/matroska @ 000002b15b9e5e00] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.48 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.344x
Conversion failed!
```

Trying to initialize the device with

```
ffmpeg.exe -init_hw_device d3d11va=qsv:MFX_IMPL_hw_any -hwaccel qsv
```

ffmpeg picks the Nvidia GPU

```
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 00000182bc06d600] Using device 10de:25bc (NVIDIA RTX A1000 6GB Laptop GPU).
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
```

How can I choose Intel Xe instead?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1428442/using-ffmpeg-to-encode-a-video-to-h264-using-intel-quicksync) is likely relevant.

Comment: Are you sure your Intel Xe GPU model supports AV1 encoding? Is it working with `h264_qsv` (for example)? Try updating the Xe GPU driver.

Comment: Thank you @Rotem, I did not know that Xe came in varying capability levels. How does one find the version / gen level of the GPU? And further than that where does get supported encoders. Google searches take me to Intel marketing material. Already bummed about the Nvidia card not able to do AV1 encoding. Bracing for disappointment on the Intel GPU...

Comment: As far as I know, Intel descrete GPUs support AV1 encoding. Modern internal GPU (built in the CPU) supports AV1 decoding, but encoding is supported only by the latest Gen 14 Meteor Lake (known as Core Ultra), that is still very rare. Look for your specific CPU/GPU model...

Comment: Thanks once again. Looking at the CPU version is what is needed [for those who might come to this thread later].